# Iterate through triple nested dictionary

Tags: c#

I understand, that it sounds a little bit strange, but I use triple nested dictionary in my program. It is the most suitable form for my data representation.

Code sample:

```
Dictionary<string, IDictionary> outerDictionary;
Dictionary<string, IDictionary> middleDictionary;
Dictionary<string, string> innerDictionary;
```

As you can suspect from names : innerDictionary is "Value" of middleDictionary and middleDictionary is "Value" of outerDictionary;

And I am trying to iterate through it, I need to **get values from the inner Dictionary**. I think I got stucked with this simple task.

Would really appreciate any help. 
Thanks in advance.

---

PS > Thanks a lot for all your help!

Comment: You would need nested for loops I imagine.

Comment: If you cannot use your chosen datastructure perhaps it's not the most suitable?

Comment: If you have `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>> outerDictionary`, then you can get all values as `string[] values = outerDictionary.SelectMany(p => p.Value.SelectMany(pp => pp.Value.Values)).ToArray();`.

Comment: I have this structure in my app and it is working fine, but at some moment I have to pass the outerDictionary to another method and get values of innerDictionary. 
For some reasons I have trouble whith iterating through the whole datastructure. 
I need just simple code (it can be pseudo code) of iterating algorithm for this specific datastructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `outerDictionary` is declared like this

```
Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>> outerDictionary;
```

you can iterate the innermost values like this:

```
var innermost = outerDictionary.Values
   .SelectMany(v1 => v1.Values.SelectMany(v2 => v2.Values));
```

If for some reason you are using non-generic dictionaries, but you are on .NET 3.5 or later, you fix this by adding a call to `Cast<>`, like this:

```
var innermost = outerDictionary.Values.Cast<Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>>
    .SelectMany(v1 => v1.Values.SelectMany(v2 => v2.Values));
```

Comment: Thanks! worked like charm!

Answer (score 4):

If you just want a flat list of *all* values, you can do that with a chained `SelectMany`:

```
outerDictionary.SelectMany(d => d.Value)  // middle Dictinoary
               .SelectMany(d => d.Value)
               .Select(kvp => kvp.Value); // inner Dictionary
```

Comment: I think you mean `Values`

Comment: @Xiaoy312 I'm not so sure, the item in the `SelectMany` will be a `KeyValuePair<Key, Value>` so the property is `Value`. It will return an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.

Comment: @D Stanley Ah, it is missing a final `.Select(kvp => kvp.Value)` to get the `IEnumerable<string>` return. And it assumes the type you are iterating is something like: `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>`.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth You are correct. I thought it would be of the type of `TValue`.

Answer (score 3):

Brute force:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, IDictionary> entryOuter in outerDictionary)
{
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, IDictionary> entryMiddle in entryOuter.Value)
    {
        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in entryMiddle.Value)
        {
            // do something with entry.Value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `Values` instead of `Value`?

Comment: Value is a a dict for both entryOuter and entryMiddle, so no I did not :)

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the `Values` property is an enumeration of all values contained; so you could use

```
foreach ( var middleDictionary in outerDictionary.Values )
{
  foreach ( var innerDictionary in outerDictionary.Values )
  {
    foreach ( string iString in innerDictionary.Values )
    {
      // your code
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be using a different data structure that's easier to think about than tripledecker Dictionaries. Even if you don't, you should definitely use *typed* Dictionaries:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>> TripleDictionary;
```

You can then itereate throgh them like so:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IDictionary> first in TripleDictionary)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IDictionary> second in first.Value)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> third in second.Value)
        {
            string x = third.Value;
            // Do stuff
        }
    } 
}
```

Implicit types will make it more readable:

```
foreach (var first in TripleDictionary)
{
    foreach (var second in first.Value)
    {
        foreach (var third in second.Value)
        {
            string x = third.Value;
            // Do stuff
        }
    } 
}
```